# Updating an existing AWS Resource using Cloudformation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

So I have a dynamodb table provisioned via cloudformation stack. Now I would like to update the dynamodb table to have mutilple GSI's.

The problem here is i dont have access to the CF Template that was used to initially create the dynamodb table.

Now, can i use a different CF Template to update the existing resource with additional config I am looking for referencing the ARN of the dynamodb table? If so, how do it achieve it?

Comment: Can't you just apply the change through the console? Given that you can't make changes with the existing template?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem here is i dont have access to the CF Template

The source code of a stack template is **available in AWS Console**, under **Template** window. Thus, you can copy and paste it, modify and update the stack.

[image]

Edit:

Based on the additional info in the comments, it is possible that the stack has [drifted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html#what-is-drift). If this is the case, then the template code given in the console is **in-valid**.

[Drift detection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/detect-drift-stack.html) can be used to inspect such possibility.

Comment: Actually, to add a comment to this, at my work place we are not allowed to re-use the same CF template, due to governance issues. should have mentioned it in my actual post.

Comment: @RohitR I'm not sure what do you mean? That's the entire point of using templates - you can reuse them easily.

Comment: In my organization, the CF template used for the initial provisioning is tightly controlled, not sure if they would let us reuse the same template.

Comment: @RohitR Sorry. I can't answer that. You may ask at your work place. Otherwise, what exactly are you expected to do? Write the same template from scratch?

Comment: Yeah, the new template would only have the additional config as required.

Comment: @RohitR Yes. So to achieve this, you copy the existing template from the console and add new config as required. You can't write minimalistic template wtih only changed properties/resources. If you deploy such template, existing resources not in the new template would simply be deleted.

Comment: @RohitR You can always do some experimentation on sample stacks and see how the updates would work.

Comment: Got it, one more question, so reusing the CFT with a new cloudformation stack is that an acceptable solution? As I would not have access to the old CF stack.

Comment: @RohitR The template in the console shown is the one currently deployed. But maybe you mean that you have a stack drift? This off course would mean that such template would not be valid and you should use Drift Detection feature to inspect such possibility.

Comment: Hmm, i need to dig around this feature.

Comment: @RohitR I will update the answer with Drift. This could be the only reason why you shouldn't use the template from the console. Because you already drifted, then the template in console is simply invalid :-(